# igraph community_optimal_modularity takes no weight argument

Tags: python, graph, igraph, modularity, weighted

I try to use the community_optimal_modularity function from igraph in python. The documentation

http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#community_optimal_modularity

http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#community_optimal_modularity

claims that feedind the keyword "weights" would consider edge weights.

Unfortunately it does not, as it seems:

```
import numpy as np
import igraph
gra = igraph.Graph.Full(10)
gra.es["weight"] = np.random.rand(gra.ecount())
gra.community_optimal_modularity(weights="weight")
```

leads to "community_optimal_modularity() takes no arguments (1 given)", while the same code works without the keyword specification for the last command. I use igraph version 0.7.0, the most recent one.

Is it possible to consider weights in the community detection via optimal modularity??

Comment: Are you sure you are using version 0.7.0? What does `igraph.__version__` say?

Comment: '0.7', sorry, I assumed this is 0.7.0

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
gra.community_optimal_modularity(weights= gra.es["weight"])
```

Worked for me.